# Error 3807 in teradata when trying to run a query

Tags: sql, teradata

TERADATA DATABASE

I am getting more rows returning when I do a left join. My base population in my volatile table is 559,157 rows. And what I am trying to do is only have the 559,157 rows from the base population return. But after running this query:

```
SELECT distinct a.*, b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, b.column5, b.column6, c.column3, SUM(c.column3) AS Total_Column3_Profit, AVG(c.column3) AS Column3_Profit_Average
,CASE 
WHEN b.column5 < a.column6 1
      ELSE 0
      END as column_open_flag
,CASE
WHEN a.column4 < 580 THEN 1
     WHEN a.column4 between 580 and 619 THEN 2
     WHEN a.column4 between 620 and 639 THEN 3
     WHEN a.column4 between 640 and 659 THEN 4
     WHEN a.column4 between 660 and 679 THEN 5
     WHEN a.column4 between 680 and 699 THEN 6
     WHEN a.column4 between 700 and 739 THEN 7
     WHEN a.column4 >= 740 THEN 8
     ELSE 0
     END as column4_band
FROM volatile_table1 a
LEFT JOIN database_table1 b
ON a.column1 = b.column0
LEFT JOIN volatile_table2 c
ON a.column1 = c.column2
GROUP BY a.column1
,a.column2
,a.column3
,a.column4
,a.column5
,a.column6
,b.column1
,b.column2
,b.column3
,b.column4
,b.column5
,b.column6
,c.column3
```

I now end up with over 2,000,000 rows returning. So I wanted to try a UNION clause. Here's my updated query:

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.column4, a.column5, a.column6
,CASE 
WHEN b.column5 < a.column6 1
      ELSE 0
      END as column_open_flag,
CASE
WHEN a.column4 < 580 THEN 1
     WHEN a.column4 between 580 and 619 THEN 2
     WHEN a.column4 between 620 and 639 THEN 3
     WHEN a.column4 between 640 and 659 THEN 4
     WHEN a.column4 between 660 and 679 THEN 5
     WHEN a.column4 between 680 and 699 THEN 6
     WHEN a.column4 between 700 and 739 THEN 7
     WHEN a.column4 >= 740 THEN 8
     ELSE 0
     END as column4_band
FROM volatile_table1 a
UNION
SELECT b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, b.column5, b.column6
FROM database_table1 b
UNION
SELECT c.column3, SUM(c.column3) AS Total_Column3_Profit, AVG(c.column3) AS Column3_Profit_Average
FROM volatile_table2 c
GROUP BY a.column1
,a.column2
,a.column3
,a.column4
,a.column5
,a.column6
,b.column1
,b.column2
,b.column3
,b.column4
,b.column5
,b.column6
,c.column3
```

Now I keep getting the 3807 error: Object 'a' does not exist. I ran a

```
HELP volatile table
```

query and it says both volatile tables do exist. Could someone please point me in the direction of my error? (I also tried removing the first case statement that refers to b.column5<a.column 6. Same error).

EDIT:

I updated to this from comments and now I get error 3653.'All select-lists do not contain the same number of expressions:

```
SELECT distinct a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.column4, a.column5, a.column6, b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, b.column5, b.column6, c.column3, SUM(column3) AS Total_Profit, AVG(column3) AS Profit_Averag
,CASE 
WHEN b.column5 < a.column6 1
      ELSE 0
      END as column_open_flag
,CASE
WHEN a.column4 < 580 THEN 1
     WHEN a.column4 between 580 and 619 THEN 2
     WHEN a.column4 between 620 and 639 THEN 3
     WHEN a.column4 between 640 and 659 THEN 4
     WHEN a.column4 between 660 and 679 THEN 5
     WHEN a.column4 between 680 and 699 THEN 6
     WHEN a.column4 between 700 and 739 THEN 7
     WHEN a.column4 >= 740 THEN 8
     ELSE 0
     END as column4_band
FROM 
(
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.column4, a.column5, a.column6
FROM volatile_table1 a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.column1, b.column2, b.column3, b.column4, b.column5, b.column6
FROM database_table1 b
UNION ALL
SELECT c.column3, SUM(c.column3) AS Total_Column3_Profit, AVG(c.column3) AS Column3_Profit_Average
FROM volatile_table2 c
GROUP BY 1
) d
GROUP BY a.column1
,a.column2
,a.column3
,a.column4
,a.column5
,a.column6
,b.column1
,b.column2
,b.column3
,b.column4
,b.column5
,b.column6
,c.column3
```

Comment: The GROUP BY belongs to the most recent SELECT/FROM.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN typically return more rows than an INNER JOIN, that's its purpose.

Comment: I'd try doing UNION ALL in a derived table (sort of subquery), and GROUP BY its result.

Comment: @jarlh I am confused. I edited my original comment with this update (ignore that it just says union, I ran the union all) but now I get error 3653. 'All select lists do not contain the same number of expressions.

Comment: Make it easier for us all, including yourself - simplify the problem! [mcve]

Comment: What are the PK-FK-relations b etween thiose tables? You might need to aggregate earlier = before the joins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aggregate after doing a union all, then use a subquery or CTE.  I think the query would look something like this:

```
select . . .
from (select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, . . .
      union all
      select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, . . .
      union all
      select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, . . .
     ) abc
group by GROUP BY a_column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
```

Comment: I am confused. I edited my original comment with this update (ignore that it just says union, I ran the union all) but now I get error 3653. 'All select lists do not contain the same number of expressions.

Comment: @InvisibleInk . . . You need to fix the `union all` so all subqueries *do* have the same columns.